# Creating HTML table using Asp.net MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a dynamic table using MVC Model. This is my Model.

```
public class PrescriptionEditModel
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Medicine List")]
    public List<PrescriptionMedicineModel> PrescriptionList { get; set; }

}
```

public class PrescriptionMedicineModel
    {

```
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Medicine")]
    public Guid MedicineId { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [Display(Name = "Prescription Duration")]
    public Guid PrescriptionDurationId { get; set; }

    public string NumberOf { get; set; }
}
```

And My Controller code is

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.PatientId = new SelectList(db.Patients.Where(h => h.HospitalId == hp.HospitalId), "Id", "FirstName");
        ViewBag.MedicineId = new SelectList(db.Medicines.Where(h => h.HospitalId == hp.HospitalId), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.PrescriptionFrequencyId = new SelectList(db.PrescriptionFrequencies.Where(h => h.HospitalId == hp.HospitalId), "Id", "Name");

        PrescriptionMedicineModel prescription = new PrescriptionMedicineModel()
        {
             MedicineId = Guid.Empty,
             PrescriptionDurationId = Guid.Empty,
             PrescriptionFrequencyId = Guid.Empty,
             PrescriptionWhentoTakeId = Guid.Empty
        };
        List<PrescriptionMedicineModel> newPrescriptionList = new List<PrescriptionMedicineModel>();
        newPrescriptionList.Add(prescription);

        PrescriptionEditModel newModel = new PrescriptionEditModel()
        {
            CaseHistory = null,
             DoctorName =null,
             HospitalId = hp.HospitalId,
              PatientId = Guid.Empty,
              PrescriptionDate = null,
              PrescriptionList = newPrescriptionList
        };
        return View(newModel);
    }
```

And My View is

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Medicine Name</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PrescriptionList.Count; i++)
   {
   <tr>
      <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.PrescriptionList[i].MedicineId, new SelectList(ViewBag.MedicineId, "Id", "Name"))</td>
      <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.PrescriptionList[i].PrescriptionDurationId, new SelectList(ViewBag.PrescriptionFrequencyId, "Id", "Name"))</td>
   </tr>
   }
</tbody>
```

This is giving an error saying "DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'.]".

I am trying to create list of medicine with list of items to allow the users edit the details of the medicine. User has to be given the ability to edit the items.

The DropDownListFor is not binding the items to the dropdown.

Any thoughts

Comment: Whats the `@model` in the View (html.cs)? The error is correct; neither of your models contain a property Id or Name. Hmm, I'll check a reference but I'm pretty sure...

Comment: @model  Custom.Models.PrescriptionEditModel

Comment: When I do dropdownlists, I specify properties on the Model, eg: `new SelectList(_context.Team, "TeamId", "Name", employee.TeamId)`

Comment: Yes, I have this new SelectList(ViewBag.MedicineId, "Id", "Name"))

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I believe your Id and Name fields don't match the model, see how my model has these two properties:

View:

```
@model XYZ.Models.Adviser

<div class="form-">
    <label asp-for="PracticeId" class="control-label">Practice</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("PracticeId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PracticeId)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
private void PopulatePracticesDropDownList(object selectedPractice = null)
{
    var practicesQuery = from d in _context.Practice
                             .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
                             .Select(grp => grp.First())
                         orderby d.Name
                         select d;
    ViewBag.PracticeId = new SelectList(practicesQuery, "ID", "Name", selectedPractice);
}
```

Model, it has properties ID and Name:

```
public class Practice
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Practice Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}

public class Adviser
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Adviser Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PracticeId { get; set; }
    
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
    public string Practice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the single item dropdown list. When I try to create table using list of model I am getting that error. I already have  Html.DropDownList("VendorId", null, "Select Vendor", htmlAttributes: new { class = "form-control", required = "required" })

Comment: You might need to pre/post fix an #ID to uniquely identify them, if its complaining about you already having it declared.